# Ahk multiple click regions at the same time

Tags: autohotkey

So I'm trying to create a script that clicks a specific coord across 9 positions on the screen at the same time.  With the game I'm playing it has to be at the same time or else it won't work,  my main problem is I don't know how to word the command. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible (physically or programmatically) to click in more than one place at exactly the same time. Would clicking these positions sequentially as quickly as AHK can send work?

Comment: Can try to set the mouse delay to -1 and see if that works.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetMouseDelay.htm